# Format zero currency value with {0:C} in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, currency-formatting

I am trying to format a zero currency value as an empty string, so that when the currency value is `0.00` then an empty string gets displayed rather than `$0.00`.
This code is part of an ASP.Net app that will display currency value to end user.

I have used following code to achieve this goal.

**Question** : Is it possible to achieve this by just using `{0:C}` format string or another version of this format string instead of using `if then else` coding for this? If I use `###,###,###.##` as the data format string then an empty string shows for zero currency value and also I get rid of the `if then else` coding but for non-zero values no currency symbol shows.

```
If Double.Parse(Decimal.Parse(CDec(currencyValue))) = 0 Then
    charValue = Nothing
Else
    charValue = String.Format("{0:C}", CDec(currencyValue))
End If
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up using the following code, which is working fine. `If` is better than `IIf` because it does short-circuiting, which means that `IIf` will evaluate all expressions whether the condition is true or false but `If` will evaluate the first expression only if condition is true and evaluate the second expression only if condition is false.

```
Dim d As Decimal
Decimal.TryParse(currencyValue, d)
charValue = If(d = 0D, Nothing, String.Format("{0:C}", d))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way using formatting to display an empty string.
But you can write it like:

```
charValue = If( currencyValue = 0D, "", currencyValue.ToString("C") )
```

using the [If Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx).

Also this is something I would not do:

```
If Double.Parse(Decimal.Parse(CDec(currencyValue))) = 0 Then
```

If `currencyValue` is `Decimal`:

```
If (currencyValue = 0D) Then
```

If `currencyValue` is `Double`:

```
If (currencyValue = 0R) Then
```

Also, if you are using a database and this is a Sql Server mind [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can when using `C` or the other similar standard formats, since they are already defining a culture-specific format that will include a format for zero.

But if you specify your own custom format, you can specify three different formats separated by `;`s, one each for positive numbers, negative numbers, and zero, respectively.

For example (giving an empty string for the zero format, resulting in blank zeroes):

```
charValue = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;""""}", CDec(currencyValue))
```

And from what I can see, omitting the format for negative gives a default that matches the positive, whereas omitting the format for zero gives blank, which is what you're looking for, so this should be sufficient as well:

```
charValue = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00;;}", CDec(currencyValue))
```

(Using whichever custom format you wish.)

UPDATE: You can get the current currency symbol and manually put it into your custom format. IE:

```
Dim symbol = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
charValue = String.Format("{0}{1:#,##0.00;;}", symbol, CDec(currencyValue))
```

From the sound of it, though, I think I would actually recommend doing basically what you started with, maybe with an extension method.

```
<Extension>
Public Function ToCurrencyString(pValue As Decimal) As String
   Return IIf(pValue = 0, "", pValue.ToString("C"))
End Function

Dim someValue As Decimal = 1.23
Console.WriteLine(someValue.ToCurrencyString())
```

This gives you exactly what you're looking for. The exact same format as `C` gives, but with blank zeroes.

Comment: For non-zero values, the culture specific currency symbol will not be included in the formatted value if I use your code. I need the currency symbol for non-zero values.

Comment: @Sunil You can use `Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` to get the currency symbol.